# Auto-generation of a unique ID using COBOL

Tags: cobol

I'm new to COBOL and I would like to know how I could auto-generate a unique ID for every single transaction. For example, the auto-generation of a tracking ID.

Comment: Would you mind sharing with us what you have tried so far, if anything? It helps us understand what you've tried and avoids us suggesting solutions that were already dismissed by you.

Comment: The simplest way is to "add one" to a transaction count that you keep globally.   If you have N uniquely identifiable sets of programs, attach the program instance 1..N to the front of the count.  If you are never sure of how many programs are running, you can call a random number generator (make sure it is good to 128 bits) and use that; the chances of two IDs matching if this is done right is quite small (this is how MS GUIDs work as a first order explanation).

Comment: You may be new to COBOL, but that doesn't mean we dont' need to know compiler/vendor, OS, the type of program you have, whether you have colleagues, local standards, a program specification, etc. Without more information @IraBaxter's comment is as good as it gets, and is a often a fair answer once we do know a lot more about your particular case. Just in case it answers your question, No, there is no FUNCTION to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

UUID/GUID is an universally unique identifier, and it can be generated using COBOL intrinsic function,

```
Display "Unique Identifier: " FUNCTION UUID4
```

Output should look something like,

```
Unique Identifier:192caea2-a913-4f05-84d8-d62c46c3aff9
```

This function is supported from COBOL 6.

reference https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.1?topic=functions-uuid4

Answer (score 0):

This is not easily done for a globally unique ID, but it is not hard to simulate using the data you might have on hand at the time of the transaction, consider:

```
01 Unique-ID.
  05 UI-Customer-Num      Pic 9(?).
  05 UI-Date              Pic 9(8).
  05 UT-Time              Pic 9(7).
*>Populate with Compute UI-Random = 999999999 * Function Random()
  05 UI-Random            Pic 9(8).
```

Assuming you have a customer number, you can genereate a unique id down to the tenth of a second with data that you will possess in the transaction.  Just add a large random number to the end of that and you have a unique ID.

If it is important that the tracking ID does not provide any data give back any data to the casual reader, you can take the final Unique-ID and run it through a one way hash, like SHA1, SHA2, SHA256, whatever.